# Installing Apache Maven

Tags: java, maven, command-line, window, instructions

On windows, I am trying to install Maven by following the instructions from [`here`](https://maven.apache.org/install.html). The step that states `"Add the bin directory of the created directory apache-maven-3.3.9 to the PATH environment variable"` is not making much sense to me. Could someone that has successfully installed Maven please explain what this step involves. I have already set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: google `add path environment variable windows`... the bin folder is where the maven executable lives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link you provided, there are more clear instructions:

> Adding to PATH: Add the unpacked distribution’s bin directory to your user PATH nvironment variable by opening up the system properties (WinKey + Pause), selecting the “Advanced” tab, and the “Environment Variables” button, then adding or selecting the PATH variable in the user variables with the value C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin. The same dialog can be used to set JAVA_HOME to the location of your JDK, e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
>
> Open a new command prompt (Winkey + R then type cmd) and run mvn -v to verify the installation.

Did you try this?

Answer (score 2):

> Add the bin directory of the created directory apache-maven-3.3.9 to
>   the PATH environment variable

This is to allow you run mvn command from anywhere. Otherwise you will have to use either the full path of mvn command or run it form that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to the maven bin folder into your windows PATH variable.  Here is an image reference.  Hope that helps.

[image]